# Implementación con EventAggregator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto Windows Forms, implementando EventAggretator estoy tomando como referencia un manual [Publisher/Subscriber Pattern With Event /Delegate and EventAggregator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/publisher-or-subscriber-pattern-with-event-or-delegate-and-e/)

En la segunda parte del manual se implementa EventAggregator e podido hacer toda la implementación pero hay una parte donde no contempla una clase que se llama `MyMessage`.

Muestro código

```
public class Publisher
{
    private EventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public Publisher(EventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void PublisMessage()
    {
        _eventAggregator.Publish(new MyMessage());
        _eventAggregator.Publish(10);
    }
}`
```

Otra clase, uno de los problemas es que en esta clase Subscriber en el constructor cuando uso la clase MyMessage me pide dos parámetros, `eve.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, Test);` no logro darle una solución para terminar con la implementación.

```
`public class Subscriber
    {
        private Subscription<MyMessage> myMessageToken;
        private Subscription<int> intToken;
        private EventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public Subscriber(EventAggregator eve)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eve;
        eve.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, Test);
    }

    private void IntTest(int obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
        _eventAggregator.UnSbscribe(intToken);
    }

    private void Test(MyMessage test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
        _eventAggregator.UnSbscribe(myMessageToken);
    }
}`
```

No encuentro la definición de `MyMessage` supongo que esa clase tengo que crearla yo, si alguien me puede dar un alcance ahí estoy dejando el link del tutorial que estoy utilizando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si lo he entendido del todo bien pero ¿lo que buscas es una posible implementación de `MyMessage`?
Pues por ejemplo algo así:

```
 public class MyMessage : EventArgs
{
    public MyMessage()
    {
        //Lo que quieras
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "cualquiera";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acertada tu respuesta, el otro problema que tenía era un error de sintaxis que ya corregí  `eve.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this.Test);`

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que MyMessage sea una implementación de `TMessageType`

ya que:

> `public void Publish<TMessageType>(TMessageType message)`: is a method
>   to publish messages. As in the code, this method receives messages as
>   input then filters out a list of all subscribers by message type and
>   publishes messages to the subscriber.

O sea que el mensaje que recibe como parámetro el método Publish es de tipo `TMessageType` . O sea, que puede ser, una instancia de un objeto de la misma  `TMessageType` o de una clase hija.

Creo que el template para esa clase es la siguiente:

```
public class MessageArgument<T> : EventArgs  
{  
    public T Message { get;  set; }  
    public MessageArgument(T message)  
    {  
        Message = message;  
    }  
}
```

Del mismo artículo, donde explica la implementación con Event Delegate.

Comment: Hola el TMessageType es como si pusiera T pero TMessageType según la implementación puede ser cualquier tipo de objeto, lo mas probable es que yo tenga que crear esa clase o mensaje. Voy a tratar de improvisar algo, lo que tu estas mostrando es la primera implementación.

Comment: Claro, yo digo que tu clase va a ser muy similar, sino idéntica a MessageArgument

Comment: Si implemento como me propones tendría que pasar un parámetro cuando utilice la clase que me sugieres.